# image is not uploaded in Public/Storage/images in laravel

Tags: laravel, filesystems, image-upload

I want to upload an image and store in a folder. from my code, I am getting the name of the image but didn't save it in a folder. The path to store the image is:- /public/storage/images.What can I do?
**Controller:-**

```
if($req->hasFile('image'))
{
return $req->image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $req->file('image')->store('/images');
}
```

**View:-**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="file">Image:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">          
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" placeholder="Choose photo" name="image">
</div>
</div>
```

**Route:-**

```
Route::view('Blog','pages.Blog');
Route::post('Blog','BlogController@Blogsinsertion');
```

**Filesystem:-**

```
'public' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root' => 'storage/',
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function Blogsinsertion(Request $request)
    {
        //.....


        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

            $image = $request->file('image');
            $name = time().rand(1, 99999) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $Path = public_path('/storage/images');
            $image->move($Path, $name);

            //save name in db

            //yourmodel->image =  $name;


        }

        //........
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is caused because you are already `return`ing before the `store()` call so the file is not actually saved.

Also, Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) has instructions on a suggested way of setting up public disk so that everything can be neat in the storage folder by creating a symlink between `/public/storage` to `/storage/app/public` but you can change the location as needed. once you point the public disk in your filesystem config file to the new symlinked path then you can try the following code:

```
if($req->hasFile('image'))
{
    // This line will save and then returns the saved file name
    return $req->file('image')->store('/images','public');
}
```

If what you are trying to do is to save the uploaded file with the same name instead of the default hashed name then you can use the `storeAs()` method instead like so:

```
if($req->hasFile('image'))
{
    $uploadedFile = $req->file('image');

    // This line will save with same name and then returns the saved file name
    return $uploadedFile->storeAs('/images', $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(),'public');
}
```

Comment: I have used your code but still, it doesn't get saved in the images folder. instead, it gives me a path like this:- images/Desert.jpg

Comment: @HarshaGandhi I'm sorry I misread your question. The code I provided was working but I think your config filesystem was not pointing to the intended folder so it is probably saved in `storage/images/Desert.jpg`. I have edited my answer with new code and a link to the laravel documentation that outline a suggested way of setting up public disk, but it's up to you if you want to follow that guideline